# FileNotFoundException although find returns absolute path

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the API of [draftable](https://draftable.com) to compare two PDF's and it works fine if I use two documents from their documentation. When I define two local files I get an `java.io.FileNotFoundException: version1.pdf (No such file or directory)`

API of draftable: https://api.draftable.com/api-explorer#!/Comparison/createComparison

In the API there is a possibility to upload two local files and it works fine. Do they upload it and store it on their end and use a public facing URL to use it on their API again?

My current code:

```
logger.info("Main started");

        String accountId = "*****"; // From https://api.draftable.com/account/credentials under "Account ID"
        String authToken = "*****"; // From the same page, under "Auth Token"

        /**
         * Demo with Local Files
         **/
        File leftFile = new File("version1.pdf");
        File rightFile = new File("version2.pdf");
        logger.info("Left File: " + leftFile.getAbsolutePath());
        logger.info("Right File: " + rightFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Side left = Side.create(leftFile, "pdf");
        Side right = Side.create(rightFile, "pdf");
        logger.info("Left Document: " + left);
        logger.info("Right Document: " + right);
        
        Comparisons comparisons = new Comparisons(accountId, authToken);

        try {
            logger.info("---CREATING COMPARISON---");
            Comparison comparison = comparisons.createComparison(left, right);
            String viewerURL = comparisons.signedViewerURL(comparison.getIdentifier(), Duration.ofMinutes(30), false);

            System.out.println("Comparison created: " + comparison);
            System.out.println("Viewer URL (expires in 30 min): " + viewerURL);
            logger.info("---COMPARISON COMPLETED---");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
```

This is the console log I'm getting:

```
14:18:31.722 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - Main started
14:18:31.724 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - Left File: /Users/In0cenT/Documents/Dev/Test_pdfDiff/version1.pdf
14:18:31.724 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - Right File: /Users/In0cenT/Documents/Dev/Test_pdfDiff/version2.pdf
14:18:31.732 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - Left Document: com.draftable.api.client.Comparisons$Side@44a59da3
14:18:31.732 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - Right Document: com.draftable.api.client.Comparisons$Side@27e47833
14:18:31.733 [main] INFO  example.NewComparison - ---CREATING COMPARISON---
14:18:31.740 [main] ERROR example.NewComparison - java.io.FileNotFoundException: version1.pdf (No such file or directory)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try providing the paths of the file as string and a second parameter "pdf"

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the files with `leftFile.exists()` and `rightFile.exists()`.
I think the problem is that you don't have these files in your path.

Comment: Thanks for that hint the file doesn't seem to exist but I get the correct absolutePath returned...

Comment: You create a pointing class to the file with new file(). this does not mean that the file actually exists. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html . The doc says "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames" for File object.